# Excel - How to filter Top 10 for specific column value in a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I a pretty basic pivot table with the following setup:

Columns: Month
Rows: ProductName
Values: SumOfPrice

So the pivot table looks like:

```
 Product Name     Jan     Feb     Mar
 hat              $50     $100    $50
 shirt            $75     $225    $10
 pants            $10     $25     $300
 gloves           $10     $75     $200
 shoes            $100    $350    $100
```

I'm trying to filter to get the Top 3 by SumOfPrice for March. It *should* look like:

```
 Product Name     Jan     Feb     Mar
 pants            $10     $25     $300
 gloves           $10     $75     $200
 shoes            $100    $350    $100
```

If I apply a "Top 3" filter, it gives the top 3 of the total of SumOfPrice. If I right click Mar and try to apply a Top 3 filter, it does nothing.

How can I get the top 3 by SumOfPrice for March?

Thanks!

Comment: have you right clicked the product name column and gone to filter -> top 10? Cant see why that wouldnt work unless the values are not properly set as currency

Comment: Yes, but that filters it by the total for each product, not by March only.

Answer (score 1):

In the PivotTable **mark** the column with the **SumOfPrice** for March *(see red circle in image below)* and then you can sort it with the sort-menu *(see blue circle below)*.

*I only have a German Excel available here but menu should be on the same position in every language.*

[image]

Comment: This would work, but it still shows the the items that are outside of the Top 3.

Comment: Hi Jeff, the only thing I could find so far is: Click on the filter symbol at Row Labels --> Got to the menu Value Filters --> There you can find the option "Top10" --> Once you click this you can create a TopDown-List based on a column. See also the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkfH2pvI84s The only problem that remains is that the TopDown-List is not shown in a descending order but I will try to research a solution for that.

Comment: The only solution I have so far for the sorting is that once you have done the process in my comment above you can apply the sorting as described in my answer and only the Top3 will be shown.

Comment: Michi, thank you for the help! However applying the filter at the Row Label will filter the top 3 by the total SumOfPrice, not for March only.